# Call wordpress from command line?

Tags: wordpress, shell, command-line

I'm wondering if there's a way to call a page from wordpress from the linux command line (without using `wget`).

I mean, what i want is to do something like this:

*The command line :* (call some php file and pass a relative url as parameter)

```
$ php /var/www/something.php /my_blog/last_post
```

*The response :*

```
<div class='post'>
    <!-- the last post content -->
<div>
```

I've been googling and looking in the Wordpress doc but i couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your time!

**Note:** If you're familiar with Cakephp, what i want is to do something like the [Shell & Tasks](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1107/Creating-Shells-Tasks) but for wordpress

**Solution:**

I've created a file in the root of the WP folder, called command.php:

```
<?php
include('wp-blog-header.php');
// call the WP functions and stuff, according to the parameters
?>
```

to call it:

```
$ php command.php my_args
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this support forum entry](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-there-a-command-line-interface-for-wordpress-like-drush-for-drupal), there doesn't seem to be a CLI interface for WordPress.

There seems to have been a [CLI theme](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-cli/) but it is outdated and no longer under active development.

However, it *should* be possible to write a simple PHP script that includes `wp-blog-header.php` and fetches the content you need. I have never tried including `wp-blog-header.php` in CLI mode so I don't know for sure whether it will work, but it is definitely worth a shot.

Comment: tested & works like a charm!! Thanks Pekka =) i've edited the question to show the answer

Answer (score 8):

Yes, using [wp-cli](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli). Available commands;

```
wp core [download|config|install|install_network|version|update|update_db]
wp db [create|drop|optimize|repair|connect|cli|query|export|import]
wp eval-file
wp eval
wp export [validate_arguments]
wp generate [posts|users]
wp home
wp option [add|update|delete|get]
wp plugin [activate|deactivate|toggle|path|update|uninstall|delete|status|install]
wp post-meta [get|delete|add|update]
wp post [create|update|delete]
wp theme [activate|path|delete|status|install|update]
wp transient [get|set|delete|type]
wp user-meta [get|delete|add|update]
wp user [list|delete|create|update]
```